# Using variable columns in VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

While working on a macro in VBA I can't figure out the following issue:

This is a part of the code

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=SUM(CreateResultsDebit!C[34])-DebitAnalysis!RC[-1]"
Range("B3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=SUM(CreateResultsDebit!C[35])-DebitAnalysis!RC[-1]"
Range("B4").Select
```

Now, I have hardcoded the column reference C[34] and C[35]. Is there a way to use, for instance, an iterator as a variable between the brackets? If I try this myself it doesn't yield any result.

Thank you. Peter.

Comment: Yes, there is. But can you be more specific about what you are trying to do?

Comment: I have 15 columns and around 1,200 rows. It need to summate all values inside a column and this summation should be stored in, for instance B3. Now I have 15 parts of the 2 I showed above, but I would be easier if I could implement a loop.

Answer (score 2):

ok... you need to combine a variable and a string... it is like:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(CreateResultsDebit!C[" & i & "])-DebitAnalysis!RC[-1]"
```

to be a bit more specific: (in your code, you set the formula first and then select another cell... I assume that you want the `C[34]` in B2 and `C[35]` in B3......)

```
Dim i As Long
For i = 2 to 3
  Range("B" & i).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(CreateResultsDebit!C[" & 32 + i & "])-DebitAnalysis!RC[-1]"
Next
```

In the first cycle (i = 2) it will go for cell B2 and use `C[34]` (32 + i). In the second cycle, those two values are 1 higher (if you go for `i` from 2 to 30, then it will go for cell B30 in last cycle and use `C[62]` in your formula)

**EDIT**
Another easy way is the use of R1C1 to set multiple cells. For this you would need to change your formula a bit and the code would look like this:

```
Range("B2:B9").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(INDEX(CreateResultsDebit!C[33]:C[51],,ROW()))-CreateResultsDebit!RC[-1]"
```

This would do the same without any loops ;)

Comment: I need to store the sum of column C[34] in a different cell than the sum of column C[35]

Comment: @Peter added the full loop for your case and also a loop-less way to do it for all cells in one step

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will be of help to you, if I understand you correctly. It will sum the columns from left to right and place them in one row consecutively.

```
Dim i as Integer
Dim iLastColumn as Long
Dim startRange as Range

Set startRange = Range("B3")
iLastColumn = Cells(1,Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
For i = 1 To iLastColumn
    startRange.Offset(1,i).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(CreateResultsDebit!C[" & i & "])-DebitAnalysis!RC[-1]"
Next i
```

Comment: If you would, could you please mark this as an accepted answer if you successfully used it? Thanks!